# Laravel home route works but the rest are not working after hosting

Tags: laravel, hosting

I have hosted my laravel application on online server (subdomain) and only the home routes works.What can be the problem?.

works:

```
http//:test.mydomin.com
```

Not working

```
http//:test.mydomin.com/test
```

Comment: I faced a similar problem, when hosting on an apache server, i solved this by editing the httpd.conf, allowoverride was set no none on one level.

Comment: You need to be more specific like on which server are you hosting it and its configuratin file too

Comment: Check this [Link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/why-do-my-laravel-routes-not-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the hosting I use it's Web server is not Apache but IIS and the below configuration on web.config solved my problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration
```